# Why don't images move when I set the specifications in CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I am a beginner and can not find the answer to my problem.

When I use top, bottom, left and right, the image doesn't move it just stays in one place.
The images didn't show up when top and left in feature class in CSS were set to 0, even though circle appears without top and left being set to exact number because it is set to absolute, as is feature class.

Could someone please enlighten me on my journey to learn web design because I am sure I will need this sort of thing in the future

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, blue);
}

nav {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
  flex-basis: 500px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 150px;
}

.links {
  flex: 2;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.links ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.links ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.information {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -10%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.circle {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.feature img {
  width: 70px;
}

.feature {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 450px;
}

.processor {
  top: 250px;
  right: 50px;
}

.display {
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 350px;
}

.battery {
  bottom: 350px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="information">
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="feature">
        <div class="camera">
          <img src="\Users\Maša\Documents\maša\programiranje\spletne strani\spletka1\camera.png">
          <p>camera is fancy</p>
        </div>
        <div class="processor">
          <img src="\Users\Maša\Documents\maša\programiranje\spletne strani\spletka1\processor.png">
        </div>
        <div class="display">
          <img src="\Users\Maša\Documents\maša\programiranje\spletne strani\spletka1\display.png">
        </div>
        <div class="battery">
          <img src="\Users\Maša\Documents\maša\programiranje\spletne strani\spletka1\battery.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set `img { position: absolute }`

Comment: I already tried that, but it just moves al the images a bit above, the previous location. I can not move the images as I want them to move, they move in unity but do not move accordingly to the stand alone specifications I set below in the CSS code